# Is it possible to set image instead of thumbTintColor in uiswitch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswitch

I am currently using default `UISwitch`.

Is it possible to set image instead of `thumbTintColor` property and also change image when state is on or off? Is it possible in default switch or should I use custom switch?

Comment: You need a custom switch class.

Comment: currently I am working in this demo.  http://www.raywenderlich.com/23424/photoshop-for-developers-creating-a-custom-uiswitch

Comment: but I am not able to change image on state change.

Comment: any help from your side??

Answer (score 0):

UISwitch has the onImage and offImage UIImage properties. Set these after initialization and they will toggle automatically when the on state changes.

Comment: Those properties don't do anything as of iOS 7.0.

Comment: Yep you're correct. A custom class is needed, since the UIImage properties will need to be added and implemented.

Comment: is it possible to change image on state change in default switch:   [mySwitch setThumbTintColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"enabled-icon.png"]]];

Comment: Be careful when using colorWithPatternImage! Only very small pattern images should be used. Otherwise you will abuse your memory usage bigtime!! As clever as that solution is, would recommend using a custom class with UIImage properties instead...

Comment: I am using this demo but I can't change image when state change.   http://www.raywenderlich.com/23424/photoshop-for-developers-creating-a-custom-uiswitch

Comment: are you able to change the image on state change?

Answer (score 0):

I found interesting solution may be it helps.

```
    NSArray *array = [self.mySwitch subviewsWithClass:[UIImageView class]];
    for (UIImageView *imageView in array) {
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-youtube.png"];
    }
```

Hear I used method from UIView category

```
- (NSArray*)subviewsWithClass:(Class)class
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    if ([self isKindOfClass:class]) {
        [array addObject:self];
    }
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        [array addObjectsFromArray:[subview subviewsWithClass:class]];
    }
    return array;
}
```

Image size is {57, 43.5}. Circle radius is 15(with shadow)

I understand that it is not very good way to solve. But if you really need it helps.